# Return not working as expected

Tags: javascript

```
var Car = function (year, make, model) {
         var printc = "You car is" + this.year + this.make + this.model;    
         return printc;
    }
var mycar = new Car(2010, "Hyundai", "Elantra");
console.log(mycar.printc);
```

Console.log is printing undefined. Why?
My expected output is : *You car is 2010 Hyundai Elantra*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var Car = function (year, make, model) {
     var printc = "You car is" + year + make + model;    
     return printc;
}

var mycar = Car(2010, "Hyundai", "Elantra");
console.log(mycar);
```

Comment: Thanks, I am wondering why _this_ needed to be removed and why 'mycar.printc' need to be changed to just 'mycar' to make it work ..... Isn't 'printc' a property of 'Car' object. And you access properties of an object using the dot notation.... Sorry, if my statement seems silly, just trying to improve my js skills .... Thanks again ...

Comment: Why on earth would you want to return a `string` from an object instatiator? This is very confusing and difficult to maintain. `printc` should be a member var of `Car`. This is terrible coding advice!

Comment: This is a modification of your code just to make it work, the correct way is the way that @BenM offered.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Ben. Actually, it was trying to return a 'function' not a 'string'. The var 'printc' was wrapped inside a function. But because it wasn't working  I removed the wrapper function for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3):

You're returning the value of `printc`, not assigning it to the `Car` object. Also, `this.year` will always be undefined, unless you assign them to the `Car` object manually.

Try the following:

```
var Car = function (year, make, model) 
{
     this.printc = "You car is" + year + make + model;    
}

var mycar = new Car(2010, "Hyundai", "Elantra");

// Correctly returns: You car is2010HyundaiElantra
console.log(mycar.printc);
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/0dvrrg90/)

Notice that spaces are not preserved, so you may wish to update the `printc` assignment as follows:

```
 this.printc = "You car is " + year + ' ' + make + ' ' + model;
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, I am trying to understand the usage of 'return'. Is it possible to print values  using 'return' statement as I have tried in my original code ?

Comment: Yes, but then you shouldn't be use the `new` keyword. You need: `console.log(Car(2010, "Hyundai", "Elantra"))`.

Comment: ok, I tried that, then it prints, _Your car is undefined undefined undefined_

Comment: Thanks Ben, after removing this from year, make, model it worked.

Comment: @PuneetSharma Please consider accepting this as the correct answer. The example posted which you have accepted is very poor.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use ES6 class:

```js
'use strict';

class Car {
  constructor(year, make, model) {
    this.year = year;
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
  }

  printC() {
    return `Your car is ${this.year} ${this.make} ${this.model}`;
  }
}

const myCar = new Car(2010, "Hyundai", "Elantra");
document.write(myCar.printC());
```